# p12 certificate installed issue

Tags: iphone, pkcs#12

I am trying to insalled p12 certificate but gives below error:

"Unable to import an item"
"The content of this item cannot be retrieved".

Password are correct. But the certificate is not displayed under "Keychain -> My Certificate" section.

Can anyone let me know what can be an issue?

One more thing, certificate is there under "Keychain -> Certificates" section. But there is not expand button.

When I get info of that certificate, it's give some extra information as below:

Extension:  Certificate Authority Information Access

Critical: NO

Method #1: Online Certificate Status Protocol

URL: ocsp.apple.com/ocsp-wwdr01

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have the private key associated with the certificate?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. Yes, I have private key password of the certificate. And it's correct. But it gives error "Unable to import an item" "The content of this item cannot be retrieved". I think it's problem of Keychain->Preference and set the certificate as "OCSP" but not sure. Do you know anything about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your comments...

...leave the settings default. I encounter this issue before. I end up revoking all related certificates & private keys and re-requesting certificate with new key & certificate signing request (CSR).